# Connect MySQL Workbench with XAMPP MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I spent two days trying to figure this one out. Basically I couldn't connect to the localhost MySQL database installed by XAMPP 1.7.4 using MySQL Workbench. I got a socket connection error (1061) or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple workaround for this is simply to add the following line to your `my.cnf` :

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

This way you can connect from any server or interface.

Answer (score 0):

Is this error 10061?  Please give a full trace of the error.

Just checking a few things:

1. Are you sure you are connecting to localhost on port 3306?
2. Is MySQL started?
3. Do you have the following line in your `my.ini` file?

   ```
   bind-address=127.0.0.1
   ```

Comment: Thanks @slotishtype, actually I tried with `bind-address=127.0.0.1`, but it did not work.